# Send basic message to logstash using python-logstash and remove unnecessary info data

Tags: python, logstash, elk

I'm sending data to Logstash through UDP using ([python-logstash](https://pypi.org/project/python-logstash/))

The thing is that the @message Elastic field contains a lot of information I don't need. Like the timestamp, version, level, type, etc.

I only need the exact text I am highlighting in the below screenshot

[image]

The script is very basic:

```
import logging
import logstash
import sys

host = '<HOSTNAME>'
test_logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
test_logger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, <PORTNUMBER>, version=1))
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test logstash info message.')
```

Is there a way to send a message without all those values?, like in this screenshot (actually it is not in a json format, so that's even better):

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove fields in Logstash using the `remove_field` option inside a `mutate` filter, but some fields cannot be removed, `@timestamp` is one of those fields for example.

You can use the following configuration in your logstash pipeline to remove fields.

```
filter {
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "field1", "field2" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks leandrojmp for your response!!, the problem with removing fields with the mutate plugin is that, in the future, I don't know how many fields I will receive in Logstash, or their names, so it will complicate scalability a bit. I think I was complicating things, this can be done easily, I'll post the solution (that worked for my case) in a comment.

Comment: You can try to use the [prune](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html) filter to pass a whitelist with the names of the fields that should be kept in the output message.

Comment: Oh man, that is a good one you know! I'm sure I'll use it in the future. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I was complicating things using the python-logstash logging handler. It's a good tool but for this specific case it will not work.
As I am using UDP, I don't need the server to reply or anything, I just need to send a basic message without any structure, this can be done by using the **nc** utility.

In case anyone needs this in the future, the command look like this:

```
echo "MESSAGE HERE" | nc -u <HOST/IP> <PORT>
```

Example: *echo "Hello, World!" | nc -u localhost 5090*

If you need to accomplish this using a python script, just send the data to the UDP port using this script:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "<HOST/IP>"
UDP_PORT = <PORT>
MESSAGE = "This is a test"
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Here is an screenshot with the result in Logstash
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEOlx.png)